# Process creation/exit callback in Go lang

Tags: go, process

On MAC OS I want process create/exit (more so exit) callbacks in Golang. Once the process exits I have to do some activity.
Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you start this process from your go program ?

Comment: No. This is for any process created.

Answer (score 1):

From [run](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Run) command documentation:

> Run starts the specified command and waits for it to complete.

You can run a command with:

```
cmd := exec.Command("firefox")

err := cmd.Run()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// DO SOMETHING AFTER PROCESS EXIT
```